# ace editor is not working in socket.io node app

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ace-editor

In my Socket app, I'm trying to send programming code as a message to another client. If run the HTML only it shows the Ace editor perfectly. But when I run node app.js the ace editor doesn't work.I have downloaded ace-builds and installed npm ace-code-editor in the app, but nothing changes 
 here is my code
    app.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    })
    socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
        console.log("message: " + msg);
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});

http.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

index.html

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Socket.IO </title>


<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    #m {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }



</style>
<script src="/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
    var editor = window.ace.edit("m");
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
        editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        var myvar = setInterval(task, 100)

        function task() {

            var code=editor.getValue();
            socket.emit('chat message',code);

        }
        socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
            editor.setValue("the new text here");
            });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>


<div id="m">function foo(items) {
    var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
    return x;
}   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Need a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling `window.ace.edit("m");` before that element becomes available.
Move script tag to the end of the file, or move ace initialization into $ call.

Comment: tried that .but no luck.
There are 2 errors in web console.
1 . GET http://localhost:3000/ace.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) at (index:24)
2 . Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'editor' of undefined
    at (index):38

Comment: in your example there is no `localhost:3000/ace.js`, so your code is probably somehow changed, trying to load it instead of `ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js`